# KVM, qemu, libvirt no DHCP on bridge

Tags: kvm, dhcp, bridge, libvirt

After I restart firewall on the host machine, I no longer get DHCP on guests until I restart `libvirtd.service`

I am providing two network captures, one before restarting FW on the host (`dhcp_ok.pcap`) and one after (`dhcp_nok.pcap`). Both of them are captured on guest machine.

[dhcp_ok](https://ufile.io/ivuhocnw)

[dhcp_nok](https://ufile.io/7e4rxlke)

Can someone please guide me where to look further, I'm currently out of ideas.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is known and documented:
[Instead we document that if you run service iptables restart, you need to send SIGHUP to libvirt to make it recreate its rules.](https://libvirt.org/firewall.html)